# Is there a way to change float on different screen size?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm not sure if I will be able to explain it clearly and if this is possible. I only have a basic grasp of HTML/CSS. I'm looking for a way to have a floating element **not** float when viewed from a smaller screen (mobile device). I have an image floating on the left side of a paragraph, but when viewed from mobile, the image with the text side-by-side gets too crowded. Is there a way to make it float on the left side normally, but appear on top of the text when viewed in smaller screens? Thanks!

Comment: See [http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Comment: Thank you, Pravesh!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is to define Media Queries. Media queries are like css triggers that defines in which resolutions certain rules will be applied.

```
.div img {
    float: left;
}

/*This will cause the img receive float none rule when screen is smaller than 768px*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .div img {
        float: none;
    }
}
```

There is a complete guide you can check out right [here](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/an-introduction-to-css3-media-queries.html).

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I'm looking for. This explains it well.

Comment: You're welcome! Check this article too: https://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/

Answer (score 0):

Using [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) should be what you need.

For example.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .content {
        float: none;
    }
}
```

Basically that says if the screen size is less then 768px then the class content won't have any float.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called MediaQueries:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

You will need something like:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px){
     yourelementselector {
       ... your CSS... 
     }
}
```